Are there cases of /n/ dropping entirely before a bilabial consonant?
I have heard of many cases where /n/ becomes /m/ before a labiodental or bilabial consonant, like pronouncing "information" as "imformation," and I have also heard of cases where /m/ assimilates into /b/. In English there's "lamb," "plumber," "bomb," etc.
Are there cases in some language where these two things happen in sequence? So in the end it is pronounces with just an /m/.
Also, are there cases where the /m/ assimilates instead of the /b/?

It's funny that I have heard a lot of people pronouncing all kinds of things but I have never heard of many cases of people pronouning things a particular way.

Yes, there are well-known examples of both, even in languages both geographically and genetically close to English.
The plosive assimilating – Celtic
The Insular Celtic languages – Goidelic (consisting of Irish, Scottish and Manx Gaelic) and Brythonic (Welsh, Cornish and Breton) – all display various forms of now grammaticalised initial consonant mutations, which originated from various vowels and consonants being lost word-finally, but the sandhi changes they’d been involved in (which generally also applied word-internally) remaining.
One of those changes was that clusters of nasal + plosive were reduced to single sounds in various ways:

the place of articulation is based on the plosive everywhere (i.e. /nb/ ends up being bilabial, /mk/ ends up being velar)
the voicing is based on an interplay between the erstwhile nasal and plosive in different ways in the two branches:

in Goidelic, it’s based on the nasal in such a way that the plosive becomes ‘one step more voiced’ (i.e. /p/ becomes /b/, /b/ becomes /m/, /m/ remains the same)
in Brythonic (I don’t know much about Cornish and Breton so by ‘Brythonic’ I really just mean Welsh), it’s based on the plosive



To give example outcomes:
Goidelic

/nb/ > /m/: place of articulation is bilabial based on /b/; voicing takes /b/ ‘down’ to /m/
/nk/ > /g/: place of articulation is velar based on /k/; voicing takes /k/ ‘down’ to /g/
/mt/ > /d/: place of articulation is dental based on /t/; voicing takes /t/ ‘down’ to /d/

(Incidentally, the exact same change as in Goidelic is also currently taking place in Greek, though in two stages: stage one is the progressive voicing assimilation, which is complete throughout the language; stage two is the loss of the nasal, which is still optional and dia-/sociolectal, so you’ll hear πέντε ‘five’ pronounced both /ˈpende/ and /ˈpede/.)
Brythonic

/nb/ > /m/: place of articulation is bilabial based on /b/; voicing is voiced based on /b/ = voiced bilabial nasal
/nk/ > /ŋ̊/: place of articulation is velar based on /k/; voicing is voiceless based on /k/ = voiceless velar nasal
/mt/ > /n̥/: place of articulation is dental based on /t/; voicing is voiceless based on /t/ = voiceless dental nasal

 
The nasal assimilating – Norse
A prominent feature of Old Norse, in particular western dialects, is that nasals assimilate to following plosives. Before voiced plosives, the nasal assimilates in place of articulation but remains nasal; before voiceless plosives, it assimilates completely to yield a geminate plosive.
This assimilation means that:

/nb, mb/ > /mb/ (*lambaz ‘lamb’ > Icel. lamb)
/ng, mg/ > /ŋg/ (*jungaz ‘young’ > Icel. ungur)
/nd, md/ > /nd/ (*landą ‘land’ > Icel. land)
/np, mp/ > /pp/ (*swampu- ‘mushroom’ > Icel. sveppur)
/nk, mk/ > /kk/ (*drinkan- ‘drink’ > Icel. drekka)
/nt, mt/ > /tt/ (*brantaz- ‘steep’ > Icel. brattur)

In the continental Scandinavian languages, the voiced clusters have – to varying degrees – subsequently been simplified, with the plosive assimilating completely to the nasal. This change is most complete in Danish, where the first three of those words are now lam /lamˀ/, ung /ɔŋˀ/ and land /lanˀ/ with no plosive at all. (The little /ˀ/ represents stød, which is not directly related to the historical plosive.)
Conversely, the full assimilation to geminate plosives is least complete in Danish (and Swedish): the Danish outcome of *swampu- ‘mushroom’ is svamp, and for *brantaz- both brat and brant (dialectal) exist – though *drinkan- is still drikke. Some of these seemingly restored nasal clusters are not actual restitutions, but rather the result of extensive later influence from German, which never had the assimilation.
